# Flutter BottomAppBar final height is 2 pixels bigger than the one set

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a form screen where I want to control the scale of each section, for that I'm using the following pattern:

```
var _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
var scaffoldWithoutAppBarHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height - _mediaQueryData.viewPadding.vertical - kToolbarHeight;
var heightUnit = scaffoldWithoutAppBarHeight / 12;
```

This allows me to use it in containers like this:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: theme.appBarTheme.iconTheme,
        actionsIconTheme: theme.appBarTheme.actionsIconTheme,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                _parking.name,
                style: theme.appBarTheme.textTheme.body2
                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              Text(
                _parking.address,
                style: theme.appBarTheme.textTheme.body1
                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white60),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: heightUnit * 11, // <--HERE
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: (heightUnit * 11) * 0.25, // <-- AND HERE
                width: double.infinity,
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 30,
                  vertical: 15,
                ),
                child: //CHILD HERE,
              Container(
                height: (heightUnit * 11) * 0.75, // <-- AND HERE
                width: double.infinity,
                child: //CHILD HERE,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CheckoutBottomAppBar(
        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.check,
        label: 'Some text',
        action: () {},
      ),
    );
```

The `CheckoutBottomAppBar` widget is just a wrapper for the the following `BottomAppBar`:

```
BottomAppBar(
      color: theme.primaryColor,
      child: Container(
        height: heightUnit - 2,  <-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        child: FlatButton(
          textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.accent,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(icon),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              Text(label),
            ],
          ),
          onPressed: action,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I use `SingleChildScrollView` to avoid keyboard collisions however the height must be precise to avoid small scrolling when no keyboard is shown on the screen.
Everything works fine and `SingleChildScrollView` allows me to scroll vertically if a keyboard pops up but when there is no keyboard the `BottomAppBar` takes 2 extra pixels of height that I had to workaround as shown but I wonder (since it took me some time to realize that) where that behavior comes from, why the `BottomAppBar` is adding 2 extra pixels to it's height?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with different screen height/density? Is it always exactly 2 pixels?
You make a bunch of float number calculations, that may be truncated and sum up to 2 pixels

Comment: I did after reading your comment :) with different devices it wasn't just those 2 pixels so I suppose I'm making something wrong when I'm trying to make that SingleChildScrollView fit nice between BottomAppBar and AppBar.